# UIScrollView not updating and displaying properly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im having problem in my `UIscrollView`,this is what I have done: Whenever a user picks an image (Multiple or Single) in camera roll thru a `Imagepicker`, I want to display it in my UIScrollView. I was able to display it, but when I go to the `Imagepicker` again then pick again an image,it doesnt update the `UIScrollView`, I tried putting my `[self createScrollView]` in my `viewDidAppear` but It recreates the `UIScrollView` but not update it, so the old images and new images are combined together. So I have put them in `viewDidLoad`but It only update when I go to another `View Controller` then back again.

//  My `UIScrollView` with thumbnail image

```
- (void) createScrollView {
    self.slotBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43, 370, 300, 143)];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.slotBg.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
    [self.slotBg.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.slotBg];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,134.0f)];
    [slotBg addSubview:self.scrollView];


    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 60);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 

        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        if (column == 4) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(330, (row+1) * 60 + 10)];
}
```

//   in my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
       for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
        { 
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
            NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

                NSLog(@"file exists");
            } 
        } 
        NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images count]);
        [self createScrollView];
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [self createScrollView];

    [_thumbs removeAllObjects];
    UIView *removeView;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {
    while((removeView = [scrollView viewWithTag:i]) != nil) {
        [removeView removeFromSuperview];
    }

        { 
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
            NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
                NSLog(@"file exists");
            } 
        } 
        NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images count]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the `[self setNeedsDisplay];` method for view controllers. It tells the device to "redraw the view, it has been updated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points:

1. Check for your data source. If image has been saved correctly in your documents directory or not.
2. No need to create scroll view and its parent view again. Move below code from `createScrollView` to `viewDidLoad`. these view should be created only once.

self.slotBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43, 370, 300, 143)];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.slotBg.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
    [self.slotBg.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.slotBg];

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,134.0f)];
[slotBg addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

Now, from viewDidAppear, first update your _thumbs array (data source). Then call createScrollView function. Inside this function, first remove all the subviews using tag from UIScrollView. Add all the thumbs again as you have done. Then call [self setNeedsDisplay] before returning from createScrollView.

Comment: how to update `_thumbs array (data source)`, I tried `_thumbs reloadData];` but not working. And how to remove all the subviews using tag from UIScrollView. Add all the thumbs again?

Comment: [_thumbs removeAllObjects]; to make it empty then addObjects into it. To remove views for scrool view, [[scrollView viewWithTag: i] removeFromSuperView]; Here i should iterated by 0 to _thumbs.count.

Comment: Have u checked, your _thumbs array is having one more member?

Comment: I mean when you select an image from image picker, the number of objects in _thumbs array are updated or not? if yes, then problem is with UI. If no, then problem is with _thumbs array.

Comment: yes its updated but not in view. I mean the array is updated but doesn't display/update in view

Comment: Then follow the exact steps as I have mentioned in the answer. Also paste updated code, so I can check.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for the tip.