# UIScrollView not loading/updating properly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im having problem with my `UISCrollView`, `UIScrollVIew` is in my `View2Controller`, my `UIScrollView` has thumbnail of images, which I imported from my `ImagePicker` picked images(multiple/single images). I have put my `[self createScrollView];` in `viewDidAppear`, So at my first load of the view only the `UIScrollView`, obviously because I havent picked images yet. So after I picked its not updating in my view. But my images.count are updating in the my debugger. It's not updating in View, but when I go to another `ViewController` then return again to `View2Controller`, it loads the images in my `UIScrollView`,then when I add again images it's not updating. Why is it like that?.

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];
}

- (void) createScrollView {

    [scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 75);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 

        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        if (column == 4) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }
   [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, (row+1) * 60 + 10)];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self createScrollView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
     [super viewDidLoad];
        self.slotBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43, 370, 310, 143)];
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = self.slotBg.bounds;
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
        [self.slotBg.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
        [self.view addSubview:self.slotBg];

        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,130.0f)];
        [slotBg addSubview:self.scrollView];
            for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
            { 
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]]; 
                NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
                if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                    [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
                    NSLog(@"file exists");
                } 
            } 
            NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images count]);
}
```

EDIT: (In this part, the image can't be deleted from the view. But in my `NSDocumentDirectory` it is deleted, )

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

        _clickedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        UIAlertView *saveMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                              message:@"DELETE IMAGE？"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
        [saveMessage show];  
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];


    if([title isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        NSLog(@"YES was selected.");
        UIButton *button = _clickedButton1;
        [button removeFromSuperview];
        [_images1 objectAtIndex:button.tag];
        [_images1 removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"image removed");       
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a new question when you already have one re: the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130757/uiscrollview-not-updating-and-displaying-properly

Comment: @Kobe.o4 - How is this the same problem? This is a separate problem, but you took away my answer because I didn't answer the question you did not post yet? At any rate how is `[_images1 objectAtIndex:button.tag]; [_images1 removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];` this working? Does button.tag have an appropriate index? Furthermore, why are you collecting the object but not using it. Wouldn't it be better to do `[_images1 removeObject:button];`?

Comment: @MichaelBoselowitz, sorry for that. But `[_images1 removeObject:button];` still isn't deleting in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidAppear:` is only called once you go to a view. So when you are 'adding' the images you are only adding them to the `_images` array, they are not displayed because you are not adding them to the screen. They are displayed when you leave the view and come back because `viewDidAppear:` is called again.

To fix this, use `addImage:` to also add it to the current view.

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    int row = ?;
    int column = ?;
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];
    UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:_thumbs.count-1];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 75);
    [button setImage:thumb 
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = _thumbs.count-1; 
    [scrollView addSubview:button];
}
```

Only problem of course is how to determine the placement, aka column and row. You can do this by getting the last thumb's frame and figuring out where to place it according to screen bounds.

**Another Fix**

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];
    [self createScrollView];
}
```

Comment: You need to extend your add image. Or another solution is to just call `createScrollView` at the end of `addImage:`

Comment: You already posted `addImage:`, it's the code you gave us. I assume you already call it when you want to add an image =P. I just added that `addImage:` should also add the image to the view, instead of just the array. You should always make sure the view and the data structure backing it are consistent. So if you add to the data structure, add to the view. If you remove from the data structure, remove from the view.

Comment: You have two choices, remove all the thumbs then readd or go with my first solution, which was to just add the one thumb that you are adding to the array.

Comment: I think Im having problem deleting it. because every thumb is assign to a button, what u shown overlaps the old one. I dunno. Do you still have any solution for this?

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is, you have to elaborate more than that. Consider revising your question with more details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13023/discussion-between-michael-boselowitz-and-kobe-o4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `createScrollView` after you have updated your array of images. Maybe try moving `[self createScrollView];` to the end of your `viewDidLoad` method? Either way, you need to call `createScrollView` after you have added all of your images.